# Full open source Android build for samsung galaxy or galaxy S

Tags: android, open-source, galaxy

How can I have a full open source build running on a samsung galaxy or galaxy S?
I have seen the gaosp project, but I'm confused about what to use now that Samsung itself has open sourced parts of the code.

Comment: i've also looked at cm7 for galaxy s. what is recommended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the kernel source here: http://opensource.samsung.com/ (under mobile phones).
There is no source for the TouchWiz framework and, more importantly, several drivers are proprietary and you will need licensing agreements that are not easy to get, so you will have to end up with a mix of open closed sources. Unfortunately, there is no other option.

**Edit**: [cyanogenmod](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/17020-all-models-cyanogenmod-7-for-samsung-galaxy-s-phones-experimental/) (you already mentioned it) is the closest you will get. The question is: what are you looking for in the source code?

**2nd Edit:**
Thread about FM radio: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=837691
Broadcom driver source code: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/system/wlan/broadcom.git;a=commit;h=f427424c414886903e4ad654c143c8ce6ec10e3c

Then, jsut follow the instructions for compiling the kernel and install it on top of any of the custom ROMs you find here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=665

You don't want an opensource framework and custom apps then, don't try to compile everything from source, but only the kernel.

Comment: so if I use this kernel coupled with a standard android framework build, everything will work out ok?

Comment: I am mainly interested in the FM radio code. nothing else.

Comment: you may want to apply some patches to it to make it fully functional (e.g., take a look here: https://github.com/supercurio). It also depends on what you mean by "standard android framework build" (cm group wants to do just that) and how stable you want the phone to be.

Comment: as I said, just an android build where I have the source code of the system. I am not worried whether the sound is buggy or 3d doesnt work properly. i am doing some research on FM radio and since the N1 has the bcm4329 whose datasheet cannot be obtained, i am looking at other alternatives. I know fm radio works on the n1, but i am interested in the rds feature.

Comment: Broadcom driver: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/system/wlan/broadcom.git;a=commit;h=f427424c414886903e4ad654c143c8ce6ec10e3c

Comment: yup. they have the code for wifi and bt but not fm radio. the guys over at cm used hci to control the fm chip to a degree, but rds wasnt done :)

Comment: I believe that's the closest you will get, unfortunately.